# Trouble with understanding alpha and beta in HMM

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, hidden-markov-model

I'm implementing HMM myself and I'm stuck with this concept.

Let T be the total time steps.
$\pi$ be the initial probabilities.
A be the transition matrix.
B be emission matrix.

$\alpha_{t,i}$ represents the probability of being in state i during time t considering all the previous observations.

$$
log(\alpha_{0,i}) = log(\pi_{i}) + log(b_i(O_0))
$$

$$
log(\alpha_{t,i}) = log(\sum_{j}\alpha_{t-1,j}\cdot a_{j,i}\cdot b_i(O_t))
$$

$\beta_{t,i}$ represents the probability of being in state i during time t considering all the future observations.

$$
log(\beta_{T,i}) = 0
$$

$$
log(\beta_{t,i}) = \sum_{j}\beta_{t+1,j}\cdot a_{i,j}\cdot b_j(O_{t+1}) 
$$

$\gamma_{t,i}$ represents the probability of being in state i during time t. $\gamma_{t,i} = log(\alpha_{t,i}) + log(\beta_{t,i}) - \sum_{I=0}\alpha_{T,I}$.

However, when I use a 2D matrix to represent these log stuff where rows are time steps and columns are states. None of these rows of $\log(\alpha)$, $\log(\beta)$, $\log(\gamma)$ sum to 0. Isn't the rows represent the log probabilities? Then how to use gamma to get it's probability being in state i at time t?

Comment: Log probabilities won't in general sum to zero, which is likely the source of your confusion. Try $2 * \ln(0.5)$ or $\ln(0.9) + \ln(0.1)$ for example. Clearly those probabilities sum to 1 but their logs do not sum to 0.

Comment: If the sum isn't 0, then how to get the probability of being in state i at time t? Since the sum(exp(log_gamma)) isn't necessarily 1?